# Page not loading on wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having a really bad problem with using Wordpress. The index template is fine but am trying to create other custom pages such as Contact us and Service.When ever I create a page I keep on getting an error when I try loading it. The error is :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /rabbit/home/fgdfg/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Comment: what is in your .htaccess file?

Comment: it is: 


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rabbit/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /rabbit/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
 @shershen

Comment: 1) what page url did you create then? 2) did you turn on nice-urls in settings - here I mean - /wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Comment: I have an index page which is the template. Am trying to creaate my other pages but they will not work

Comment: what do you mean "which is the template" - all pages are rendered though template, it's another so to say layer...did you check those 2 points?

Comment: How exactly are you creating a page?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix accessing `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and basically `Save Changes`